# Accessing Data in Python Array

Tags: python, json

I am pulling in stock data and I need to access the first option that comes up in the "callExpDateMap". But, I'm not sure.

I am trying to access the first option's data by calling:

```
      xyz = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
        print(xyz)


{
    "symbol": "GOEV",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "underlying": null,
    "strategy": "SINGLE",
    "interval": 0.0,
    "isDelayed": true,
    "isIndex": false,
    "interestRate": 0.1,
    "underlyingPrice": 10.969999999999999,
    "volatility": 29.0,
    "daysToExpiration": 0.0,
    "numberOfContracts": 5,
    "putExpDateMap": {},
    "callExpDateMap": {
        "2021-06-18:3": {
            "11.5": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "GOEV_061821C11.5",
                    "description": "GOEV Jun 18 2021 11.5 Call",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 0.6,
                    "ask": 0.7,
                    "last": 0.6,
                    "mark": 0.65,
                    "bidSize": 4,
                    "askSize": 138,
                    "bidAskSize": "4X138",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 1.0,
                    "lowPrice": 0.1,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 0.1,
                    "totalVolume": 4416,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1623787194008,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1623787198521,
                    "netChange": 0.5,
                    "volatility": 195.881,
                    "delta": 0.448,
                    "gamma": 0.183,
                    "theta": -0.111,
                    "vega": 0.004,
                    "rho": 0.0,
                    "openInterest": 100,
                    "timeValue": 0.6,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 0.654,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 11.5,
                    "expirationDate": 1624046400000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 3,
                    "expirationType": "R",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1624060800000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 500.0,
                    "markChange": 0.55,
                    "markPercentChange": 554.2,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "mini": false
                }
            ]
        },
```

To access the first item, I am calling:

```
   print(xyz['callExpDateMap'][0])
```

But, that doesnt work. How do I pass the first item in the array to a separate variable?

Comment: `frist_key = xyz['callExpDateMap'].keys()[0]`
`xyz['callExpDateMap'][frist_key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you

```py
callExpDateMap = list(data['callExpDateMap'].values())
print(callExpDateMap[0])
```